# How to dismiss a showDialog when I navigate to the next page in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, flutter-layout, showdialog

I have a show dialog with CircularProgressIndicator that pops up when user press on signin.
Once the sign in function finishes, the user will navigate to the next page but the showDialog is staying on the screen. How can I dismiss it when I navigate?

```
Future googleLogin() async{
showDialog(context: context,
  barrierDismissible: false,
  builder: (context) => const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
  ),
);
try{
  final googleUser =
  await GoogleSignIn(scopes: ['profile', 'email']).signIn();
  if (googleUser == null) return;
  _user = googleUser;

  final googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;

  final credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
    accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
    idToken: googleAuth.idToken,

  );

  await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
}on FirebaseAuthException catch (e){

  Utils.showSnackBar(e.message);
}
navigatorKey.currentState!.popUntil((route) => true,);}
```

I tried using pop until but It seems like Im doing it wrong

Comment: Just use `Navigator.pop(context);`.

Comment: I have tried that but the thing is that its being closed but the user will stay in the same screen for 2 more sconds then only naviagte to the second page. instead what I want is to keep it on the screen until the the user navigates then only close it

Comment: its because I have a timer that will refresh the page every 3 seconds to check if the user has higned in or not and when he is in then he will be navigated to the Home screen. so basically, I want this progress indicator to keep loading on the screen when he pres ssign in until he navigates to the next page and then only close it

Comment: put `Navigator.pop(context);` below `await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);`.

Comment: Thanks!. Inspired by your answer, I just made a small change to put it below the flag which determine if the user is singed in.  if (FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser != null) {
      setState((){
        isGoogleAccountSingedIn = true;
      });
    }      Navigator.pop(context);

Answer (score 1):

Description:-
When Dialog box open in your screen and user want to navigate other screen.

1. Dialog will be close
2. you will be navigate new screen.

> Navigator.pop(context);

> Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500), () {
> //Add here your next screen navigation code
> });

I hope solution will helpful for you

Comment: Please add some description what you code does instead of just sharing the code.

Comment: @AlexanderDischberg Description added, Thanks for comment

Answer (score 0):

Put FutureBuilder inside showDialog:

```
googleLogin() {
  showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => FutureBuilder(
          future: GoogleSignIn(scopes: ['profile', 'email']).signIn(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                login(snapshot.data).then((value) => navigatorKey.currentState!.popUntil((route) => true,));
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                Utils.showSnackBar(snapshot.error);
                navigatorKey.currentState!.popUntil((route) => true,);
              }
              return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator.adaptive());
          }
          );
      );
}

Future login(data) async {
  _user = data;

  try {
    final googleAuth = await data.authentication;

    final credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
      accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
      idToken: googleAuth.idToken,

    );

    await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
  } catch (err) {
    Utils.showSnackBar(err.toString());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Call Navigator.pop(context) to dismiss ShowDialoue
2. Navigator.push() to move to second page

   ```
              showDialog(
                             context: context,
                             builder: (BuildContext context) {
                               return AlertDialog(
                                 title: Text(
                                   'I am ShowDialogue',
                                   style: TextStyle(
                                       color:
                                           Color(0xff4E5069).withOpacity(0.9)),
                                 ),
                                actions: [
                                   TextButton(                                
                                     onPressed: () {
                                         Navigator.pop(context);
                                         Navigator.pushNamed(
                                           context, "secondPage"
                                         );                                       
                                     },
                                     child: Text('Create'                                        
                                     ),
                                   ),
                                 ],
                               );
                             },
                           );
   ```